# radio button validation using custom validation in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have two radio buttons with two text boxes.I want below validations for that fields using custom validations by data annotations:
1.if i entered value into the text box and i didn't check the corresponding radio button it should display the message like preference is required and vice versa.

Comment: i tried this using data annotations in custom validation.I used one radio button property in model for two radio buttons.so, how to handle this situation

Comment: Could you read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then update your question please